# Run Python script from Java

Tags: java, python, digits, pycaffe

I am trying to run **.py** script in Java, but when I run the java code it doesn't show any output. What I am doing wrong? I tried with:

```
ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    //xterm will be launched, if platform is Linux.
    command.add("xterm");
    command.add("-c");
    command.add("python");
    command.add("/home/clef/Escritorio/use_archive.py");
    command.add("/home/clef/classification/STOP_WORDS.tar.gz");
    command.add("/home/clef/Escritorio/Prueba_linea/000006/6.jpg");
    command.add(" > ~/Escritorio/mike.txt");
    //command.add("--revert");    // switch to revert the patch

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    Process p = null;

    if (pb != null) {

        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (p != null) {
            try {
                p.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    ArrayList<String> allOut = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("salida");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("SALIDA-----------:");
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            allOut.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        //allOut = "0";
        //Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //System.out.println("erro3");        }
        System.out.println("error");
    }
```

The script is from NVIDIA DIGITS framewrok, but I can't run any python script from Java. If I run the **.py** script in terminal I get output:

```
Unknown file: solver.prototxt
    Unknown file: train_val.prototxt
    Processed 1/1 images in 0.076470 seconds ...
    -------- Prediction for /home/clef/Escritorio/Prueba_linea/000006/6.jpg --------
     51.4607% - "0"
      7.7899% - "1"
      5.7782% - "2"
      5.6086% - "3"
      5.2513% - "4"

    Script took 0.523756 seconds.
```

Comment: Why are you using xterm?

Comment: I also tried with /bin/bash but did not work well

Comment: You don't need to use either of those, python will run by itself...

Comment: I think so, but script doesn't work if I run it from java, I try commands like 'ls' 'cd ..' but I can't run python scripts from java.

Comment: What do you mean it 'doesn't work'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python yourapp.py");
```

Exec runs system commands, if you have python installed, this will run the python file like you would in the command terminal of your operating system.